# About tf.contrib.slim data prepare documentation

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

I have spend much time to understand how to prepare my data to feed into Slim Net. 
But I still can't quiet understand how to prepare my training data.
Is there a more detailed method for processing the training data, like Caffe ImageNet tutorial:http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TF-Slim Image models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim) Library specifically at [datasets](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim/datasets)